# Is there a way we can auto-generate create swagger spec or api blueprint for graphql

Tags: graphql, swagger-ui, apiblueprint, altair

https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/swapi
This is a sample graphql endpoint. Is there a way we can auto-generate create swagger spec or api blueprint  for graphql

Comment: Look at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-elements.js this can covert API Blueprint, Swagger or OA3 into API Elements AST in JSON that can be consume by any tool.